# Docusign responsive signing text tabs

Tags: docusignapi

I have a form that has a few fields that need to be filled in for the last signer after 2+ people have already signed it. They cannot be prefilled as they are not known at the time the document is generated.

I'm sending an HTML document to the Docusign API and have it working great for the first set of signers. The problem is when I try to add text tabs to the document (`<input data-ds-type="text" />` following [this page](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/responsive/setting-tabs/)) I receive a 400 error back from the Docusign servers with this error message:

> Some of the supplied HTML tags, attributes or CSS properties on a guided forms tabs were not allowed. Disallowed: HTML attributes [input:data-ds-type]

How can I do this?

Comment: Ben, can you email me - inbar.gazit@docusign.com and provide information like accountId, envelopeId so we can try to find this in the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your HTML is valid and all characters in it are correct.
The responsive signing HTML validator is much more strict than the one browsers typically have. a bad HTML will break the whole thing and won't let you create the envelope and the error message unfortunately right now is not as helpful as it can be, but I'll ask to improve this.

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this same issue, I had copied an input from the DS example page and couldn't see the unicode quote in my IDE. Switching it to regular quotes fixed the issue.